# Horizontal scroll bar displays at page load for sliding panel

Tags: javascript, css

I have a page that consists of multiple sections. One of the middle section needs a sliding panel on the right. However, when the page load, there is a horizontal scroll bar in the browser. Here is the jsfiddle link

Here is the HTML:

```
<div style="background-color: pink;height:100px;">
    section before the sliding panel
</div>

<div class="cd-main-content" style="height:200px;background-color:yellow">

    <a href="#0" class="cd-btn">show Panel</a>

    <div class="cd-panel from-right">
        <div class="cd-panel-container">        
            <div class="cd-panel-content ">             
                <a href="#0" class="cd-panel-close">Close</a>               
                <header class="cd-panel-header">
                    <h1>Title Goes Here</h1>
                </header>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor ...</p>
            </div> <!-- cd-panel-content -->
        </div> <!-- cd-panel-container -->
    </div> <!-- cd-panel -->

</div>

<div style="background-color: orange;height:100px;">
    section after the sliding panel
</div>
```

Here is the jsfiddel ink: https://jsfiddle.net/d61a5zqz/3/

CSS and Javascript code is in the demo.

I spent some time to get rid of the scroll bar. No success. How can I get rid of the scroll bar and **keep the sliding animation and everything else at the same time**?  If a CSS solution is available, it would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your css file.

```
body{
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

It will remove the scrollbar on the x axis.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This seems working. I wonder whether this would remove the horizontal bar when it is needed for some sections of the page. Should I add explicit css for overflow-x for those individual sections? Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Having this on the body prevents the page from having a scrollbar, however any elements inside the body would be unaffected unless they had overflow-x:inherit. By having this rule specified on the body, you would be free to have a div inside the body with it's own scroll bar. Hope this helps.